# Exception while sending CardImage from Bot

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, web, botframework

I have written code for sending the message based on the intent matching using LUIS in bot framework.
Here is my code.

```
[LuisIntent("Skype for Business")]
    public async Task Skype4Business(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(context.Activity.ServiceUrl));
        try
        {
            // return our reply to the user
            List<CardImage> cardImageList = new List<CardImage>();
            List<CardAction> buttons = new List<CardAction>();

            CardImage cardImage = new CardImage { Alt = "SpeechPic", Url = @"C:\Users\Rock\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Text Analytics\Text Analytics\Resources\Skype-for-business-2.jpg" };
            cardImages = new List<CardImage>();

            cardImages.Add(cardImage);

            CardAction skypeButton = new CardAction()
            {
                Value = "example.com/",
                Type = "openUrl",
                Title = "Skype for Business"
            };
            buttons.Add(skypeButton);

            HeroCard heroCard = new HeroCard()
            {

                Title = "Skype For Business",

                Images = cardImages,
                Buttons = buttons

            };

            var message = context.MakeMessage();
            message.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
            message.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.List;
            message.Attachments.Add(heroCard.ToAttachment());


            await context.PostAsync(message);

            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }
```

So whenever I am sending the reply from the bot if the intent is matched e.g: Skype for business. So I am replying by making card and adding cardimage and button in it. It send without any error but after sending successfully it shows me the exception too.
[image: Snapshot of exception]

I'm stuck here even i have added the try/catch clause too to handle the exception but still i am getting the exception. 
How to resolve this? 
Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't replicate your issue. Are you on the latest version of the framework?

Comment: Yes, I am on the latest version of the bot framework

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that it seems you are having a global variable `cardImages` and so, you are hitting the serialization issue because `CardImage` is not serializable.

You have two list of card images:

```
List<CardImage> cardImageList = new List<CardImage>();

cardImages = new List<CardImage>();
```

You should use the image list you are creating in the method scope (`cardImageList`) and not the global variable. Make sure to delete the global variable too.